# Laravel search facility

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to upgrade my search facility, at the moment I am listing all the skills available and once clicked it searches for handymens with that skill. Now I want to create a search box so once user inputs anything it will search and display all handymens with that skill once button is clicked. so for example 'p' would return 'Plumber'. But I am struggling hard with it so please help me, if any other files or databases need to be attached please let me know.

So basically it should be like this, user enters a character. Information is passed to skills database and find skills that match any character entered. Then because skills and handymen table are connected the output should be a list of handymen with that skill and they are defined in junction table. Once one of the links is clicked, details for specific handyman should be displayed. Ideally everything should on 1 page. I have been playing around but still cannot solve it.

This is what I get atm: NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

View:

```
    <h1>Here you can search</h1>
    <form action="{{url('details')}}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div>
            <input type='text'  name='skill'/>
        </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Search">
    </form>
     @foreach ($skills as $skill)
        <p>
            <a href="{{url('details/'.$skill->id)}}">{{$skill->skill}}</a>        
        </p>

    @endforeach
@endsection
```

Controller:

```
function search()
{
    $skills = Skill::all();
    return view('layouts/search',['skills' => $skills]);
}
function details()
{
$handymen = $skill->handymen;
$q = Input::get('skill');
if($q && $q != ''){
$searchTerms = explode(' ', $q);
$query = DB::table('skills');  // it's DB::table(), not DB::tables

if(!empty($searchTerms)){

  foreach($searchTerms as $skill) {
    $query->where('skill', 'LIKE', '%'. $skill .'%');
  }
}
$results = $query->get();

dd($results); // for debugging purpose. Use a View here
```

}

```
}
/*
function details($skillId)
{
$skill = Skill::find($skillId);
$handymen = $skill->handymen;
$skill = Input::get('skill');
$result = Handyman::where('skills','LIKE','%'.$skill.'%')
            ->orWhere('email','LIKE','%'.$skill.'%')
            ->get();
return view('layouts/details', ['skill' => $skill,'handymen' => $handymen]);
}
*/
```

Handymen database:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateHandymenTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('handymen', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('street');
        $table->string('postcode');
        $table->string('town');
        $table->string('skills');


        $table->integer('job_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('job_id')->references('id')->on('jobs')->onDelete('cascade');


        $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('handymen', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('handymen_job_id_foreign');
        $table->dropColumn('job_id');
    });
    }
}
```

Skills table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateSkillsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('skills', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('skill');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('skills');
    }
}
```

Junction table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateHandymanSkillTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('handyman_skill', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('handyman_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('skill_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::table('handyman_skill', function ($table) {
            $table->primary(['handyman_id', 'skill_id']);
            $table->foreign('handyman_id')->references('id')->on('handymen')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('skill_id')->references('id')->on('skills')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('handyman_skill');
    }
}
```

---

Route.php:

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

```
Route::get('home', 'HandymanController@home');

Route::get('search', 'HandymanController@search');

Route::post('searchTesting', 'HandymanController@searchTesting');

Route::post('details}', 'HandymanController@details');

Route::get('skilledHandyman/{handymanId}', 'HandymanController@skilledHandyman');

Route::post('jobassign', 'HandymanController@jobassign');

//Route::get('assignjob/{handymanId}', 'HandymanController@assignJob');

Route::get('addjob', 'HandymanController@addJob');

Route::post('addjform', 'HandymanController@addjForm');

Route::get('jobs', 'HandymanController@jobs');

Route::get('jobsdetails/{jobId}', 'HandymanController@jobsdetails');

Route::get('deletejob', 'HandymanController@deleteJob');

Route::post('deletejform', 'HandymanController@deletejForm');
```

});

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

1. on the `Handyman` model have a method called `skills`:

   ```
   public function skills() {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Skills');
   }
   ```
2. and on the `Skills` model have a method called handymen

   ```
   public function handymen() {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Handymen');
   }
   ```

This way we make a many to many relationship on our models

3. Than on your `details` method on the `Controller` you could do something like this:

   ```
   function details() {
       $handymen = App\Handymen::whereHas('skills', function($query) {
           if(!empty($searchTerms)){
               foreach($searchTerms as $skill) {
                  $query->where('skill', 'LIKE', '%'. $skill .'%');
               }
            }
       })->get();

      //dd($handymen);
      return view('search_results', compact('handymen'));
   }
   ```

I have not tested this, but should work.

And in your `Routes.php` file make sure you have:

```
Route::post('details', 'YourController@details');
```

Comment: keep getting same error message, how shouuld view page look like to display results of handymen that have certain skill?

Comment: still getting error message, route.php in my main post

Comment: Right I fixed that one but now I get error: HandymanController.php line 32:
Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App\Handymen' not found which is this line:  $handymen = App\Handymen::whereHas('skills', function($query) {

Comment: Well, App\Handymen should point to your Handymen model. I don;t know your directory structure..

Comment: Try changing `App\Handymen` with `Handymen`.

Comment: works well sort of. What code is needed to actually display the results? as atm I am getting empty page with search box

Comment: I have updated my answer. You have to return a view containing your `$handymen` collection, and iterate through it and show the results. Does the `dd($handymen)` output anything?

Comment: where should I see the output? there's nothing on the page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109182/discussion-between-musicvicious-and-przemek-wojtas).

Comment: ok it works but it outputs everything no matter what I type, how to tackle this?